# adding a new row in a pandas data frame basis a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, row, pandas-groupby

I have a situation where I want to add a new row after a certain condition is met. My dat frame looks like following :

```
ID            Event          Date
1             A              2019-11-12
1             B              2019-11-13
1             C              2019-11-18
1             D              2019-11-20
2             A              2019-11-20
2             B              2019-11-20
```

the moment the ID value changes from 1 to 2, I want to add a row between that. The event column cell should contain "today" as the event name and the date column should have today's date.

The output should look like :

```
 ID            Event          Date
 1             A              2019-11-12
 1             B              2019-11-13
 1             C              2019-11-18
 1             D              2019-11-20
 1             Today          2020-04-24
 2             A              2019-11-20
 2             B              2019-11-20
```

How should I achieve this?

Comment: There are also another values for `ID` column and is necessary add new row if change?

Comment: @jezrael: yes there are other values as well and the new row should be added if the value changes from one to another..Let me try your solution

Comment: Still not working?

Comment: @jezrael: Nope. The row placement is still not at the right place for a lot of IDs. I am not sure what is going wrong here, the code seems to be correct. I am looking to solve this for another major issue that I have, if that can be resolved easily. Would you mind looking at that one?

Comment: Do you think last question problem?

Comment: @jezrael: I am sorry , I didn't understand what you just said. You meant the last question I posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212472/discussion-between-django0602-and-jezrael).

Comment: yop, last posted question

Comment: yup. that is correct.. that is my major pain point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need append new rows for between each groups if there is change use:

```
df1 = (df[df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift(-1).ffill())]
       .assign(Event='today', 
               Date = pd.Timestamp.today().floor('d')))
print (df1)
   ID  Event       Date
3   1  today 2020-04-24
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
         .iloc[:-1]
         .assign(Event='today', 
                 Date = pd.Timestamp.today().floor('d')))
```

---

```
print (df1)

   ID  Event       Date
3   1  today 2020-04-24
```

And then add to original with sorting index values:

```
df = df.append(df1).sort_index(kind='mergesort')
print (df)

   ID  Event       Date
0   1      A 2019-11-12
1   1      B 2019-11-13
2   1      C 2019-11-18
3   1      D 2019-11-20
3   1  today 2020-04-24
4   2      A 2019-11-20
5   2      B 2019-11-20
```

Comment: I am not seeing the correct output. the new row that needs to be appended is in the wrong position, I am not sure about the issue what's causing it. How should I share my output to show that to you?

Comment: @Django0602 Is index default? If not sure try `df =df. reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution.

Answer (score 1):

well! there might some other ways too to do that but the one i found is like this :

1. First slice your data into two dataframes. say df1 and df2
2. Then add new dataframe to the end using df1.append(new_df)
3. next rejoin them again by using . df1.append(df2)

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   d = {'id' : [1,1,2], 'event' : ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'date':[12,21,30]}

   **id    event   date
   0   1   a   12
   1   1   b   21
   2   2   c   30**

   to_append = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1], 'event' : ['a'], 'date':[12]})

   **id    event   date
   0   1   a   12**


   df = pd.DataFrame(d)

   df1 = df.iloc[0:2, :]
   df1 = df1.append(to_append)
   df1 = df1.append(df2)

   **id    event   date
    0  1   a   12
    1  1   b   21
    0  1   a   12
    2  2   c   30**
   ```